# Importing third-party modules within a virtualenv

Tags: python, wxpython, pip, virtualenv, python-2.6

Following the trouble I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822727/unable-to-install-older-wxpython-within-virtualenv-cannot-unpack-file-cannot) trying to install an older wPython inside a virtualenv, I then downloaded the dmg directly in a browser, and (after needing to right-click on the .pkg), it successfully got installed.

When I open an intepreter, I confirm that I can `import wx`.

Yet when I recreate my `virtualenv`, activate it, and open its intepreter:

```
(venv)MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:Projet Pyderman$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84374, Aug 31 2010, 11:00:51) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wx
```

Is there a step I am missing with respect to being able to import third-party modules within a `virtualenv`?

Comment: Will the real downvoter please stand up, please stand up. So we can all be enlightened as to why a question that has resulted in a helpful answer should be be deemed "unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try creating the virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option. This will allow you to access the packages installed at system level, like the ones you install from a dmg image.

Comment: This seems to have worked, though I would have expected that allowing system packages would be the default behaviour, and that only if I were to set `--no-site-packages` would this default behaviour be overridden.

Comment: It used to be the default behaviour, but not anymore. As it says when you run `virtualenv --help`:
    --no-site-packages    DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward     compatibility.
                        Not having access to global site-packages is now the
                        default behavior.